# Asymptotic behaviour of $K$-Bessel function in transition range

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, special-functions, automorphic-forms, maass-forms

It is known that the famous mistake of Iwaniec-Sarnak in their [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2118522.pdf?&acceptTC=true&jpdConfirm=true) of $L^\infty$ norm of eigenfunction of non-cocompact arithmetic surfaces in lemma (A1) is because of they did not consider the bump of $K$-Bessel function at transition range.

1. First, I do not understand which part of the proof (sketched below) is flawed.
   An eigenfunction of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash\mathcal{H}^2$ with eigenvalue $1/4+t^2$  looks like $$\phi(z)=\sqrt{y}\sum_{n\neq0}a_nK_{it}(2\pi|n|y)e(nx).$$ First they proved a bound of sum of Fourier coefficients (Ramanujan on average) which is $(t>0)$
   $$
   \sum_{n\le N}|a_n|^2\ll e^{\pi t}(t+N).
   $$
   Then, I guess that they are using a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and an asymptote that for $t>2\pi|n|y$ $$e^{\pi t}|K_{it}(2\pi|n|y)|^2\ll (t^2-|n|^2y^2)^{-1/2},$$to deduce final final bound. The above inequality can be found [here lemma 2.3 and 2.4](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1048610117). Isn't the above asymptote correct?

2)It is mentioned in [Sarnak's letter to Morawetz (equation 43)](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Sarnak_Letter_to_Morawetz.pdf) that $K_{it}$ has a bump of size $t^{1/6}$ near $y=t$. Do we know precise asymptote of $K_{it}$ uniformly in $y$ and $t$ so that the above argument can be rectified?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a published account of the corrected proof, see Section 10 in Blomer-Holowinsky: Bounding sup-norms of cusp forms of large level, Invent. Math. 179 (2010), 645-681. See especially pages 679-680, where you can also find the precise asymptotics of $K_{it}$ in the transitional range.

Actually, a few years ago, a colleague of mine asked me about the same thing. What follows is my email response in slightly edited form (I am too busy to re-read carefully):

There are several problems with Lemma A.1 and its proof. The problems arose from not using correctly the asymptotics of $K_{ir}(y)$ in the transitional range $y\approx r$. For $|y-r|<r^{1/3}$ the function is about $e^{-\pi r/2} r^{-1/3}$ times a phase, while for $|y-r|>r^{1/3}$ it is about $e^{-\pi r/2} |y^2-r^2|^{-1/4}$ times a phase, with the additional remark that for $y$ large the exponential decay kicks in. As a consequence:

1. The display below (A.2) is wrong: $r^{-1}$ should be lowered to $r^{-4/3}$. This is not a big problem, since if we integrate from $r/2$ (instead from $r$), then the bound
   is OK (I learned these things from papers by Strömbergsson). In other words, in the line before (A.3) one should set $N=r/(4\pi Y)$. Actually (A.3) is too weak for this
   purpose, as explained below. Instead the following should be used, which is known by deeper methods:
   $$ \sum_{0<|n|<N} |\rho(n)|^2 \ll e^{\pi r} r^\epsilon N. \tag{1}$$
2. The last display on p.316 is wrong. In fact for fixed $b\geq 0$ one has
   $$ \sum_{n\neq 0} |n|^b |K_{ir}(2\pi|n|y)|^2 \ll e^{-\pi r} (r/y)^b (r^{-2/3}+1/y), $$
   and this is best possible for $2\pi y < r+O(1)$, e.g. the first term in the parantheses comes from $2\pi|n|y$ very close to $r$. This shows that the last display on p.316
   should read
   $$ |\phi(z)|^2 \ll Y^{-2} (Y+r) (y^{-1}r+Y)^2 (yr^{-2/3}+1). $$
   For the choice $Y=r/(2\pi y)$ this gives
   $$ |\phi(z)|^2 \ll (Y+r) (yr^{-2/3}+1), $$
   which is too weak eventually. Using (1) above in place of (A.3), one gets
   $$ |\phi(z)|^2 \ll r^\epsilon Y (yr^{-2/3}+1), $$
   i.e.,
   $$ \phi(z) \ll r^\epsilon (r^{1/6} + (r/y)^{1/2}) {\|\phi\|}_2. \tag{2}$$
   This is a bit weaker than Lemma A.1. In fact this is the correct version of Lemma A.1 since $\max_{0\leq x\leq 1}|\phi(x+ir/(2\pi))|$ is about $r^{1/6}{\|\phi\|}_2$.

Much the same correction is explained on pp.38-40 of [Sarnak's letter to Morawetz](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Sarnak_Letter_to_Morawetz.pdf).

A bit more detail is given in the Blomer-Holowinsky paper, on p.679. Actually, the bound on top of p.680 is only justified for $t>1$ and $y>1$, but it is valid for all
$y>0$ and all forms (including forms violating the Selberg conjecture).

**Added.** For a generalization of (2) to spherical Hecke-Maass forms over an arbitrary number field, see Lemma 9 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09360). Note that $\phi$ in that lemma satisfies ${\|\phi\|}_2=1$. Note also that (1) above was (*) in an earlier version of this post.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. One confusion is: how did you get $r^\epsilon$ term in (*)? Don't Rankin-Selberg and Hoffstein-Lockhart give $e^{\pi r}N$?

Comment: @Kunnysan: In $(*)$ we have $|\rho(n)|^2=|\rho(1)|^2.|\lambda(|n|)|^2$, where $\lambda(n)$ is the $n$-the Hecke eigenvalue. Hence $(*)$ follows from two bounds: one for $|\rho(1)|^2$, and one for $\sum_{n=1}^N |\lambda(n)|^2$. The bound for $|\rho(1)|^2$ is $e^{\pi r}r^\epsilon$, as follows from Corollary 0.3 in Hoffstein-Lockhart (note their different normalization of $\rho(n)$). The bound for $\sum_{n=1}^N |\lambda(n)|^2$ is $r^\epsilon N$, and this is due to Iwaniec. So there are two sources of $r^\epsilon$ in $(*)$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am really confused. Equation (8.15) of Iwaniec's 'Spectral Methods of Automorphic forms' does not have $r^\epsilon$ term. It is, in our language,$$N^2\mathrm{res}_{s=1} L(s,\phi\times\phi)$$ and the residue is of size $e^{\pi r}$.

Comment: @Kunnysan: (8.15) says that the sum in $(*)$ is asymptotically an absolute constant times $e^{\pi r}N$. There is no explicit error term there, i.e. it does not tell us anything about the size of the sum for small $N$, say for $N<r$. In particular, (8.15) does not yield that the sum in $(*)$ is $\ll e^{\pi r}N$. Compare this with (8.17) in Iwaniec's book and plug in $X=|s_j|$ there. You will see that the error term in (8.17) exceeds the main term provided by the asymptotic formula. The value of $(*)$ is that it provides a strong uniform upper bound, even when $N$ is very small compared to $r$.

Comment: @Kunnysan: One more small comment. In fact $(*)$ is as strong as Corollary 0.3 in Hoffstein-Lockhart, since for $N=2$ it yields $|\rho(1)|^2\ll e^{\pi r}r^\epsilon$. This also shows that without $r^\epsilon$ the bound $(*)$ would be too strong to be true.

Comment: So the only way to find uniform estimate of partial sum of Fourier coefficients is to go through Hecke eigenvalue relation with Fourier coefficient? Is there any way to find the estimate directly, without using Ramanujan on average?

Comment: Or in other words how do you estimate sum of Fourier coefficients for groups where you don't have nice Hecke relation like $\rho(n)=\rho(1)\lambda(n)$?

Comment: @Kunnysan: There are other techniques for general groups, but the resulting bounds are weaker than $(*)$ for $N$  small. See for example Theorem 3.2 in Iwaniec's book. In particular, this theorem implies that for $N>r$ we can remove $r^\epsilon$ in $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an illuminating discussion!

Comment: @Kunnysan: I am glad that I could help!